# Any Problems With Multiple Partitions on Win7 and are the Partitioning steps in Win7 similar to 98/XP?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, window

When I used to install 98/XP on a system I would create a primary partition and then allocate the rest to extended and fill that with logical partitions. Can I do the same in the windows 7 installer?

Also, will having more than one primary partition on a hard disk and installing windows 7 on one cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a very good set of defaults for partitions, just let it handle it itself. When you install windows just choose the un-partitioned drive (or delete your existing partition and then choose new new empty drive if you want to do a full clean wipe) and it will do all the work for you.